# How to exit a when a function mapped over a collection first returns true?

Tags: clojure

I want to map a function that returns a boolean over a collection and exit with true on the first true match... how would I do that?

```
(map #(true? %) [false false true false])
```

returns

```
=> (false false true false)
```

How would I simply get `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(some pred coll)` returns the first truthy `(pred x)` for `x` in `coll`, or `nil` if no such truthy value is found. Note that in Clojure, all values are truthy except `nil` and `false`. For your example:

```clj
(some identity [false false true false])
=> true
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I had tried some without the identity and it didn't work.